# adjusting UIPopoverController size based on number of rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableViewController with header and footer and only 1 section and I want to put that inside a UIPopover.

The UITable has a up to a maximum of 5 rows so I am hoping I can adjust the size of the popover according to the size of the table.

In `viewDidLoad` of the `UITableViewController`, I call a web-service which then decides how many rows there are in the table.

The problem I am facing is I dont know where to call `setPopoverContentSize`? Calling it in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `viewDidAppear:`? Call it as soon as your table view data is populated, basically.

Comment: @GuyKogus doesnt seem to work either. :(

Comment: What iOS version are you using?

Comment: I am building it on iOS6 but running it on iOS7.

Comment: Then you need to use `preferredContentSize` for iOS 7 and `contentSizeForViewInPopover` for iOS 6. You can use `respondsToSelector` to decide which property to use.

Comment: @GuyKogus i tried using `contentSizeForViewInPopover` while running it on my iOS simulator but it seems there's still no resizing being done.

Answer (score 2):

For ios7 you have to set in your Controller below method:

```
 -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     self.preferredContentSize=myTableView.contentSize;
  }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: are you referring to the UIViewController that holds the table? In my case it's a UITableViewController. Unfortunately that didnt work for me. :(

Comment: yes i edit my answer,it's worked for ios 7 as per @Guy Kogus comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed this by using delegates. So each time my web service call ends, I call a delegate method that tells the `UIViewController` showing the popover how many rows there are. Thereafter, I set the popover size by using `setPopoverContentSize: animated:`.

This method asks the main view (the one that is supposed to display the popover) to determine the size, I was thinking the better way to do it was to have the content view (the one that is to be shown) to determine its height and width but I wasnt able to achieve it that way.